# Implementing inner type's traits on outer type

Tags: struct, rust, traits

With the struct:

```
    struct U85 (
        [u8; 5]
    );
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `&U85`
   --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:11:40
    |
11  |                     s.serialize_bytes(&self[..])
    |
```

whereas when I use the simple type `[u8; 5]` everything is fine.

- What trait of `[u8; 5]` causes the indexing error?
- How can I implement it for `U85`?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait?

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks, yes, that was it.  If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x[y]` syntax is implemented with the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) traits. One catch with indexing for slices is that `x`, `x..y`, `..`, `..y`, `x..` are all different types. You can either pick-and-choose what you want to support, but if you just want to do what slices can do, you can implement it like so:

```
use std::ops::Index;
use std::slice::SliceIndex;

struct U85([u8; 5]);

impl<I> Index<I> for U85 where I: SliceIndex<[u8]> {
    type Output = I::Output;
    fn index(&self, index: I) -> &I::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}
```

If you find yourself implementing traits for wrapper types a lot, you can look into using the [derive_more](https://crates.io/crates/derive_more) crate, which will allow you to derive traits (like `Index`) that defer to the inner type.

```
use derive_more::Index;

#[derive(Index)]
struct U85([u8; 5]);
```